# Python score system

Tags: python, string

I am writing a program were add and subtract numbers from an integer to keep score. The admin and subtracting is working but I am trying to add a feature that if you add number after the word add or subtract it changes by that number, but I can’t get that to work.

```
cont = True
score = 0
num = False
while cont == True:
  q = input("add, subtract, or end: ")
  for char in q:
    n = q.isnumeric()
    if n == True:
      num = True
      num2 = q
  if num == False:
   if q.lower() == "add":
     score += 1
   elif q.lower() == "subtract" or q.lower() == "sub":
     score -= 1
   elif q.lower() == "end":
    cont = False
   print(score)
  elif num == True:
   if "add" in q.lower():
     score += num2
   elif "subtract" in q.lower() or "sub" in q.lower():
     score -= num2
   elif q.lower() == "end":
    cont = False
   print(score)
```

I expect it to add one if you type add subtract one if you type sub or subtract and end the program if you type end, that works the part that I expected and doesn’t work is that it is supposed to detect if there is a number in the string using the isnumeric() function and add or subtract that number.

Comment: Generally, to test booleans use `if X` rather than `if X == True` and use `if not Y` rather than `if Y == False`.

Comment: Should the different parts of the input be separated by spaces (or another, specific character=? Then you could have a look at [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and use it to read an entire line like 'add 1 2' at once, parse it with `str.split()`, and then perform an action based on 1) the number of elements after splitting and/or 2) the first element.

Comment: To only answer your question, you are very close! `isnumeric()` does check if your input is numeric, but q is still just a character. Replace `num2 = q` with `num2 = int(q)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code simplifies neatly to something like:

```
score = 0
while True:  # Infinite loop; we'll use `break` to end
    print("Score:", score)
    q = input("add, subtract, or end: ").lower().strip()  # lower-case, remove whitespace
    words = q.split()  # Split entry by spaces
    verb = words.pop(0)  # Remove first word

    if verb == "end":
        break

    if words and words[0].isnumeric():  # If there is a second word and it's numeric
        value = int(words[0])
    else:  # Otherwise default to 1
        value = 1

    if verb == "add":
        score += value
    elif verb == "subtract":
        score -= value
    else:
        print("Unknown verb", verb)
```